# Using SQL Server 2008 TIME column in class declaration

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I hope this makes sense, I am trying to store a SQL Server 2008 `time`(7) datatype in an object.

I am using the below to read the data into the object, but it is crashing out on the line

```
timeStart = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("timeStart"))
```

Other than changing my database field to a datetime, can anyone advise on a solution

My class declaration is:

```
public DateTime timeStart { get; set; }
public DateTime timeEnd { get; set; }

SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    Schedules sched = new Schedules()
    {
        Name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Name")),
        timeStart = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("timeStart")),
        timeEnd = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("timeEnd")),
        IntervalMinutes = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("IntervalMinutes"))
    };
    schedules.Add(sched);
}
```

Comment: "it is crashing out" is not a good description of what's happening. Is an exception thrown? If so, what does it look like?

Comment: mark mellamokb the answer if you if his answer worked for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx), you should be using the `TimeSpan` type and [`SqlDataReader.GetTimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.gettimespan.aspx).